# Show black Lines in Dark Theme on explorer window

Tags: eclipse, aptana, aptana3

I love to use dark theme for Programming.
But i have the fault, that the lines on explorer-window (which shows subfolders), doesnt become white, to see theem.

See Image: [image]

Here is a Image if i turn to a light-theme.. there you see the lines:
[image]

What can i do th have all windows with dark background, but lighter lines?